# I have a 70 amp breaker for a hot tub i'm getting rid of the new one is only 50amp can I use the same breaker?

Tags: wiring

I have a 70 amp breaker for a hot tub i'm getting rid of the new one is only 50amp can I use the same breaker ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Would you edit your question to be clearer on the amperage of the breaker, the old hot tub, and the new hot tub? (It looks like you have a 70A breaker, but the new hot tub is only rated for 50A...)

Answer (score 5):

If the manufacturer of the hot tub recommends a **maximum** circuit size of 50 amps then you should change the breaker to 50 amps. The conductors can stay the same.

If the 50 amps is a **minimum** rating for the hot tub then you can leave the 70 amp breaker and conductors.

You should always follow the manufacturer's instructions. The National Electrical Code requires it.

Good luck!